# Grafana data shown by hour

Tags: grafana

I'm using Grafana and I want to see which hours are better to perform operations. So, I want to sum the requests and show the number of requests per hour in, let say, the last week. I mean: how many requests it had from 9:00 to 10:00 despite any day of the last week (and the same for every hour).

My backend is elasticsearch, but I can gather information from a prometheus too.

Does anyone know any way to get these data shown?

The Grafana version I'm using is 7.0.3.

**EDIT**

I found a possible solution by adding the plugin for [hourly heatmaps](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/marcusolsson-hourly-heatmap-panel/)

Comment: You mean you want to group the sum of requests per hour right?. Then You can choose the interval to be one hour in the group by date histogram row.

Comment: good try, but it is not my problem.

Choosing the interval you group per hour and day. What I want is to group just by hour, regardless of the date.

Comment: I found a solution, by using a hourly heatmap plugin: https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/marcusolsson-hourly-heatmap-panel/.
It is not exactly what I wanted to have, but is enough to figure out if the problem is tied to some hours.